# SSE DJANGO REQUEST COUNT

Tags: django, server-sent-events, eventsource, event-stream, streaminghttpresponse

i still new using SSE and i have a question about SSE in Django version 3.2.5, i am using StreamingHttpResponse to send SSE response to EventSource client and it does work fine,
my question that

**why it takes to long to open the connection between backend and EventSource?**

**why it sends only 167 responses/32 seconds ?**

i tried to open the code of StreamingHttpResponse but i didn't find anything related to the number of response

here in the code

```
def sse_movies(request):
  def event_stream():
      while True:
          sleep(.2)
          yield f"data: {datetime.time(datetime.now())}\n\n"
  return StreamingHttpResponse(event_stream(), content_type='text/event-stream')
```

i am using sleep() to wait only  200/milliseconds for each iteration.
but whenever send the EventSource it waits almost 32/seconds to initiate the connection with the back-end, and after it sends 167 requests then waits 2 seconds then sends another 167 requests once more and after the second 167 is sent it waits another 32 seconds

here is the code of EventSource client

```
    let url = '/test/' +'sse/movies/'
    let sse_client = new EventSource(url)
    let movies = document.querySelector('#data-movies')
    let movies_list = document.querySelector('#messages')

    sse_client.onopen  = function(message_event) {
        console.log('opened')
    }
    console.log(sse_client)

    sse_client.onmessage =  (message_event) => {
        console.log(message_event.data)
        console.log(sse_client.readyState)
}
```

NOTE: when i remove white: True  EventSource doesn't wait and sends requests as much as possible

maybe i misunderstand something here, but i hope the somebody could help me

Comment: `.2` is not 2 milliseconds, it's 200 milliseconds or 1/5th of a second. Still doesn't explain much, but just wanted to note it

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov, Thanks for your explanation. i am still trying to figure it out but, still can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could figure out the  issue.

it was n't in the code itself, but it was related with the buffer size of the webserver

so when i edited my code to be as below it worked fine:

```
def sse_movies(request):
  def event_stream():
      body =  ''.join([letter * 6000 for letter in 'A'])
      body_len = len(body)
      print(body_len)

      while True:
          sleep(2)
          yield f"data: {body}\n\n"
  return StreamingHttpResponse(event_stream(), content_type='text/event-stream')
```

as you see above the minimum size for buffer is 6000/Characters
i don't not how much that could be in bytes), but yeah it worked Alhumdulliah)

i really don't know that much about buffer/buffer-size/..
but i thought that it could be the issue